# Syntax Auto Spacing Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax

In visual studio If I type:

```
int x=5*6+2*3;
```

It will automatically format it to:

```
int x = 5 * 6 + 2 * 3;
```

In eclipse I have to press CTRL+SHIFT+F to do this.

Is there any way I can make it happen automatically like in visual studio??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preferences** → **Java** → **Code Style** → **Formatter** → **Edit** 'Active Profile' → **White Spaces** → **Expressions** → **Operators** (and the others)

Tick all desired boxes for white spaces, then **Apply**.

To inoke the formatter in the code editor, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (default).

---

You may also set the formatter to be invoked automatically on a **Save** Action, by going to **Preferences** → **Java** → **Editor** → **Save Actions** → And tick **Format Source Code**, along with other desired configurations of course.